# IE11 Video Stuck In Seeking And Can't Change Current Time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I believe this may be a bug with IE11 / HTML5 Video Api, but was hoping someone could confirm or provide a workaround. I have tested this in Chrome/Firefox/IE11. It works fine in Chrome/Firefox but freezes up in IE11. I believe the root problem is that the video gets stuck in a 'seeking' state.

**Steps To Repo:** *(2 jsfiddle's below)*
1) open link, open console, and click on video
2) on keyboard, click up and down over and over

**Straight Javascript Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/B7hT5/50/

```
switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 38: //up
      console.log('up: ', videoPlayer.seeking, videoPlayer.currentTime, videoPlayer.duration);
      videoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
      break;

    case 40: //down
      console.log('down: ', videoPlayer.seeking, videoPlayer.currentTime, videoPlayer.duration);
      videoPlayer.currentTime = videoPlayer.duration;
      break;
}
```

**AngjularJs Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/B7hT5/49/

```
switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 38: //up
        if (!scope.videoPlayer.seeking) {
            console.log('up: ', scope.videoPlayer.currentTime, 0);
        }
        else {
            console.log('up: STUCK SEEKING');
        }
        scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        break;

    case 40: //down
        if (!scope.videoPlayer.seeking) {
            console.log('down: ', scope.videoPlayer.currentTime, scope.videoPlayer.duration);
        }
        else {
            console.log('down: STUCK SEEKING');
        }
        scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = scope.videoPlayer.duration;
        break;
}
```

In Chrome, the seeking value will switch true/false over an over. But in IE11 after a few clicks it seems to get stuck on seeking, and then the video locks up and you have to refresh the page. The seeking value could be totally unrelated, just something I noticed.